# Implementing GUID in Yii

Tags: oop, design-patterns, yii

If you have a data model in which one table is a `guid` table with just a `guid` column, and many tables have a primary key referencing that `guid`, how would you recommend incorporating this type of logic into Yii? To create a new model of any `guid`able thing, you have to create a `guid` first. Where is the right place to put this sort of logic?

Edit: To be more specific, here is the issue I am facing:

- I have a table of guids, `tbl_guid`, with one column `guid` that is a MySQL `BIGINT`
- Some tables, like `tbl_foo`, have a PK `guid` referencing `guid` in `tbl_guid`
- The `Foo` model has the relation `self::BELONGS_TO, 'Guid', 'guid'`
- I do not want to create a new guid until I am definitely ready to create `Foo`
- I'd like to somehow delay the saving of my `guid` until I'm actually saving (and have otherwise validated) `Foo`
- However, `Foo` never validates, because it doesn't have a guid.

Edit 2: I've posted my own answer, but I am hoping somebody has a better answer/improvement to suggest. Here are the issues with my answer:

- How can we force the `owner` to comply with some interface, so we don't have to throw in a bunch of conditionals to check for whether or not the `owner` has an attribute or method, etc
- Even though the database will not accept `null` for `guid`, it still seems wrong to remove `guid` from the list of required attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I've been able to come up with:

Create a new `CActiveRecordBehavior` for `guid`able models:

```
public function beforeSave() {

    if (!$this->owner->guid) {

        $guid = new Guid;
        $guid->save();

        $this->owner->guid = $guid->guid;
    }
}
```

Attach the behavior on the model, or define it in the model's `behaviors` array.

```
public function init() {
    $behavior = new GuidBehavior;
    $this->attachBehavior('GuidBehavior', $behavior);
}
```

Remove the required-ness of `guid` so validation doesn't fail:

```
array('name', 'required'), //guid isn't here
```

Test

```
$brand->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance. If you implemented my BaseModel code a while ago, you can override the `__construct()` method in the BaseModel to create an instance of the GUID class.

BaseModel:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $newGuid = new GUID();

    return $this;
}
```

See [http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#__construct-detail)

Comment: So, if I go the inheritance route, let's say I'm creating a model, but I'm not necessarily planning to `save()` it. If I go the full nine yards in creating the `guid` in my constructor (and don't save) couldn't that lead to a bunch of non-used GUID?

Comment: I see. If I do this, when I call `$model->save()` Is Yii "smart" enough to know to save the GUID first, if it is defined as a relation?

Comment: Also, overriding `__construct()` is resulting in an infinite loop for me... do you mean `init()`?